# VBA only runs on current sheet instead of whole workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My code wont run on the whole workbook just the one I'm active on. 
I want it to run on every sheet in the workbook
Probably just a simple fix

```
Sub Remove_symbol()

'remove "Â" from data

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng1 As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set Rng1 = Range(Cells.Address)

    Rng1.Replace What:="~Â", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

'and duplicates

    Rng1.Replace What:="~(pH Unit)(pH Unit)", Replacement:="(pH Unit)", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Rng1.Replace What:="~(µS/cm)(µS/cm)", Replacement:="(µS/cm)", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Rng1.Replace What:="~(mg/L)(mg/L)", Replacement:="(mg/L)", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Rng1.Replace What:="~(µg/L)(µg/L)", Replacement:="(µg/L)", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: fully qualify your range objects... `Set Rng1 = ws.Range(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a worksheet object calls `ws` for your loop, but you are not using it anywhere. You need to use it to qualify your Range object when you set it. You should also use it to qualify your Cells reference:

Update it to this:

```
Set Rng1 = ws.Range(Cells.Address)
```

or possibly this:

```
Set Rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells.Address)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Set Rng1 = Range(` needed to be `Set Rng1 = ws.Range(`
Thanks to braX for the answer in the comments